# How do I do a loop function „pointDistance()“ using R

Tags: r, loops, coordinates, distance

I have a data frame with four columns: individual identifier, date of observation, longitude co-ordinate and latitude co-ordinate.

And I am looking for the distances among the first and rest of positions (co-ordinates) grouped by individual (… separately for each individual).

I tried as follows:

library(raster)
names(spdf)
[1] "individual" "date" "utm.longitude" "utm.latitude" "longitude"

```
coordinates(spdf) <- c("utm.longitude", "utm.latitude")
proj4string(spdf) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=33 ellps=WGS84")
spdf$date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(spdf$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))

test <- for(i in unique(spdf$individual)) {
pointDistance(spdf, lonlat=FALSE)
}
test
NULL
```

Unfortunately the loop does not work. May I ask for help, how to loop it?
Thank you in advance

```
dput(spdf)
structure(list(individual = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), date = structure(c(1629141240, 1631819700, 1631992680, 
1650136980, 1651952340, 1654976400, 1655063160, 1659556080, 1661111520, 
1681914060, 1682519280), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    longitude = c(455531L, 455529L, 455528L, 455528L, 455548L, 
    455548L, 455541L, 455530L, 455526L, 455555L, 455524L), latitude = c(5557649L, 
    5557649L, 5557647L, 5557646L, 5557640L, 5557636L, 5557638L, 
    5557645L, 5557648L, 5557720L, 5557651L)), row.names = c(NA, 
11L), class = "data.frame")

str(spdf)
data.frame':    18 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ individual: int  1 2 3 1 3 2 1 3 1 2 ...
 $ date      : POSIXct, format: "2021-08-16 21:14:00" "2021-09-16 21:15:00" "2021-09-18 21:18:00" "2022-04-16 21:23:00" ...
 $ longitude : int  455531 455529 455528 455528 455548 455548 455541 455530 455526 455555 ...
 $ latitude  : int  5557649 5557649 5557647 5557646 5557640 5557636 5557638 5557645 5557648 5557720 ..
```

Roman

Comment: A `for` loop ***never returns anything***, so you are calculating a distance on each pass through the loop and then ignoring and discarding the return value. Where do you intend to **store** the calculated distance?

Comment: Hi r2evans. Thanks for interest. I would like to store them into a simple df. The first column … individual identifier and the distances into the next columns. Another alternative is the list.

Comment: … probably the list is a better solution

Comment: can you `dput(head(spdf))`and copy `structure(...)` above as data?

Comment: Hello Chris, thank you for the answer. I add “dput(spdf)” and “str(spdf)” into my question. Co-ordinates are in the format of UTM.
Roman